# Design Question: How can I maintain a stack of object

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, stack

I have a struct call 'A', which has an attribute 'i', like this:

```
typedef struct a {
   a() { i = 0;}
   int i;
} A;
```

And I would like to maintain a stack of A in my Main class:

```
class Main {
   public:  
      void save();
      void doSomethingToModifyCurrentA();
      void restore();

   private:
     A currentA;
     stack<A> aStack;
  }
```

I would like to write the function save() which save the current values of A (e.g. i) to the stack and I can go on doSomethingToModifyCurrentA() to change currentA. And then later on, I can restort A by calling restore().

My question are

- How can I allocate memory for a copy of A to the 'stack'?
- How can I pop out the copy of A and free the memory and restore the value of 'currentA'?

Comment: In C++ you don't need the typedef around your struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to reserve memory on the stack. The underlying container (deque by default) manages memory for you.

The three important methods are...

```
mystack.push (myvalue);
mystack.top ();
mystack.pop ();
```

The pop doesn't read the top value - just discards it. The top method returns a reference to the current top value, so you can write...

```
??? = mystack.top ();
mystack.top () = ???;
```

To read or overwrite the top value.

These methods translate to the following calls in the underlying deque...

```
mydeque.push_back (myvalue);
mydeque.back ();
mydeque.pop_back ();
```

Personally, I usually just use the deque directly - though strictly, the stack is better for readability and maintainability as it better expresses the intent and prevents you from doing some things incompatible with that intent.

Answer (score 3):

In the C++ STL library there is a `stack` implementation you can use and there's the push and pop methods.

`push` is used to add an item to the stack and `pop` is used to pop one off the stack.

Have a look a [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic117364.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a A& for current A. (and look into the STL's [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) for the implementation

Comment: I'd have +1'd if that answer actually answered the question :/

Comment: @rRomain: I thought I was answering an implicit question about allocating currentA, I suppose  I'd misread the question.  oh well ;)

Comment: I am using the STL's stack. I just don't know how to allocate memory/free memory of my class A when I push/pop to the stack.  All the examples I found are using stack<int>. I am looking for a stack<A> (a class).

Comment: You don't allocate or free memory when pushing or popping.  Only when creating.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that A is relatively simple (even if not just a single int as your example), you can actually solve both your questions by just using a by-value stack and letting it copy and allocate the memory.

Working from your sample code:

```
void Main::save()
{
    aStack.push(currentA);
}

void Main::restore()
{
    currentA = aStack.top();
    aStack.pop();
}
```